# Android Doesn't Recognize Image Downloaded by Flutter App

Tags: android, file, flutter, dart, client

Android Flutter app downloads an image from a server on another Android phone. After downloading, the file is unable to be opened or viewed by the phones gallery or file explorer. However, when examined by a hex editor, the downloaded file and the original file are exact copies, and when imported to windows, the "corrupt" downloaded file is view able by the Image Viewer. The only difference I could find between the files was the metadata examined by Windows. What could be the cause of this?

Original File on Android Server:
[image: photos of Downloaded file metadata]

Downloaded File On Android Client:
[image: photos of Downloaded file metadata]

Here's the code I'm using to create the file from a Uint8list:

```
  Future<File> downloadFileAndroid(Uint8List fileBytes, String fileName) async{

    var dir = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File photoFile;

    var photoDirectory = await Directory(dir.path + "/Downloader").create(recursive: true);
    photoFile = await new File(photoDirectory.path + "/" + fileName).create();
    if(await photoFile.exists()){
      await photoFile.writeAsBytes(fileBytes);// also tried flush: true
      print("Created file and it exists");
    } else {
      print("Error: tried to create file but it doesnt exist");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem when downloading an image from the internet and setting a png extention to it. Using an extention on the file name usually causes this error. Consider using https://pub.dev/packages/image_downloader to download the image using the default function in the example code. With the default option, the extension is not determined by the coder but instead by itself.